# Not matching product names in the Array List in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two array lists.

**capturedForeginProduct** : Foreign Product Names

**capturedLocalProducts** : Local Product Names

**capturedForeginProduct** Array lists contains following foreign product names.

> Washington Apple Drink
>
> Token Apple Drink
>
> Skinner Apple Drink

**capturedLocalProducts** Array list contains following local product names.

> SUNFRESH Apple Drink RTS 1L
>
> APPY FIZZ Sparkling Apple Drink
>
> APPY Apple Drink 250ml Pet Bottle

I use the following code snippet to match the product names against **capturedForeginProduct** array list to the **capturedLocalProducts** array list.

```
if(capturedForeginProduct.get(i).equals(capturedLocalProducts.get(j)))  {
```

But it is not matching any of the products. Basically my final outcome should be like follows.

> Washington Apple Drink
>
> Token Apple Drink
>
> Skinner Apple Drink

should match with,

> SUNFRESH Apple Drink RTS 1L
>
> APPY FIZZ Sparkling Apple Drink
>
> APPY Apple Drink 250ml Pet Bottle

as each of the product contains "**Apple**" wording. I do not mind whether it contains capitals or not but if the word is available then it should match.

This my code in order to carry out this particular task.

```
for (int i = 0; i < capturedForeginProduct.size(); i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < capturedLocalProducts.size(); j++) {
        //   if(capturedForeginProduct.get(i).contains("Garlic")) {
        //  if (Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(capturedLocalProducts.get(j)), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(capturedForeginProduct.get(i)).find() || capturedLocalProducts.get(j).toLowerCase().contains(capturedForeginProduct.get(i).toLowerCase())) {

        if (capturedForeginProduct.get(i).equals(capturedLocalProducts.get(j))) {
            //  if(capturedLocalProducts.get(i).equals("SUNFRESH Mango Drink RTS 1L"))  {

            log.debug("Matching Second Chance .. : " + "\t" + capturedForeginProduct.get(i) + "\t" + capturedLocalProducts.get(j));
            firstForeignProducts.add(capturedForeginProduct.get(i));
            firstLocalProducts.add(capturedLocalProducts.get(j));
        } else {
            log.debug("Un Matching Second Chance .. : " + "\t" + capturedForeginProduct.get(i) + "\t" + capturedLocalProducts.get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like classic not implementing equals() (yes and hashcode) method, but please can you post some code...

Comment: sure I will update the question @Adam

Comment: You should compare not the whole string but the parts, as I assume "Washington Apple Drink" and "SUNFRESH Apple Drink RTS 1L" are each one string - when you want to compare them according to parts of their contents, `equals` is not the right way, because `String#equals` checks for equality of the whole string.

Comment: Why do you expect "Washington Apple Drink" to return `true` when you're asking if it's equal to "SUNFRESH Apple Drink RTS 1L". Does it look equal to you ?

Comment: @alfasin yes because as the both String carries the word "Apple" it should be equal to me..

Comment: Have you heard of the enhanced for loop, it will help reduce the amount of code you need to write... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: A pig and a lion both have legs - would you consider them "equals" ? you should start working on your logic buddy...

Comment: @Smutje Is there way how I could do it then ?

Comment: @alfasin well according to my application it should be YES !! :)

Comment: Yes, split it at " " and compare the split results.

Comment: @Smutje so I have to use split method in both array lists right ?

Comment: Well, the definition should NOT be if two different strings are `equals` (something that has a *meaning* in Java), but rather: is there a word that appears in two sentences? Asking if the strings are `equals` is a totally different question.

Comment: so @alfasin any help as you have got the point well now ?

Comment: Partly, instead of comparing to strings, you have to compare the split results of the two strings each one by one.

Comment: great .. I got the point @Smutje

Comment: @DulithDeCozta sure thing buddy, I added an answer to the queue :D

Comment: @alfasin Thnxxxx Pal (Y) ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if there's a mutual word in two sentences as follows:

```
String sentence1 = "Washington Apple Drink";
String sentence2 = "SUNFRESH Apple Drink RTS 1L";

List<String> sen1 = Arrays.asList(sentence1.split(" "));
List<String> sen2 = Arrays.asList(sentence2.split(" "));

for (String s : sen1) {
    if (sen2.contains(s)) {
        System.out.println("The word " + s + " appears in both sentences");
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
The word Apple appears in both sentences
The word Drink appears in both sentences
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to split the names and compare each part.

```
String foreign = capturedForeginProduct.get(i);
String local = capturedLocalProducts.get(j);

String[] foreignWords = foreign.split(" ");
String[] localWords = local.split(" ");
```

And finally iterate over the two arrays and compare each word.